# Batch: Merge specific parts of mkv files

Tags: batch, merge, matroska

I have several Folders of MKV files. each folder contains episodes of a series with english Audio track and good quality of video and same episode with Farsi dubbed audio track (and also english) but bad quality of video track
I want to use a batch file to get video and english audio track from files like "series S01E01 eng.mkv" and Farsi audio track from "series S01E01 Far.mkv" in the same directory and set Farsi audio track as default audio track and create "series S01E01 DUB.mkv" and then next episode of series to the end of it.

Unfortunately I couldnt find a program or batch file that do this job  for all episodes, and manually it takes several hours to do more than houndred files.
What can i do? any program that do it or batch would be very helpful.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a couple of steps with ffmpeg.

1. Use `ffmpeg -i filename.mkv` to list the file information
2. From the output you'll see the streams included listed, note the numbers of the ones that you want, we hope the wanted ones have the same number in all the files, check a few. Otherwise scripting the process is not going to be simple.
3. Lets say you need to extract stream 0 and stream 2 where 0 is video and 2 is the wanted audio then `ffmpeg -i filename.mkv -c copy -map 0:0 filename.mp4` & `ffmpeg -i filename.mkv -c copy -map 0:2 filename.m4a`
4. You can then writes these separated streams to a new file `ffmpeg -i filename.mp4 -i filename.m4a -c:v copy -c:a copy filename.new.mkv`
5. Copy all the wanted video and audio files to a new directory then you can as long as their names are the same (different extension) merge them back into your wanted files.

Obviously you want to automate this, in windows in a batchfiles you can use %% as a substitution, this should be it for the merge, from the command line use only one % for substitution.

`for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%~na.mp4" -i "%%~na.m4a" -c:v copy -c:a copy "%%~na.new.mkv"`

You can if you're sure the streams are identical in each file use a similar substitution to write the separate video and audio files. NB only one % if you want to write a batch file with the line use %%

`for %a in ("*.mkv") do ffmpeg -i "%~na.mkv" -map 0:2 -c copy "%~na.m4a"` & `for %a in ("*.mkv") do ffmpeg -i "%~na.mkv" -map 0:0 -c copy "%~na.mp4"`

Comment: Thanks a lot. it was very helpful, but I still have some problems. if we have this files all in one folder:

LockeAndKeyS01E01_ENG.mkv
LockeAndKeyS01E01_DUB.mkv

I want to merge stream0 from first as Video, stream1 from second file as first audio of output mkv file (as default Dubbed audio), and stream1 from first file as second audio (english audio) and an output file name such: LockeAndKeyS01E01_NEW.mkv    

i want a batch to do it automatic for all episodes in folder.

Comment: I can't off the top of my head think of a way to easily script for pulling different streams from files then merging them. You could extract all the streams from all the files, copy the ones you want to a folder then merge them with a batch / loop command but still it is a fair bit of manual work required.